# Unbiased vs Impartial difference

Tags: word-usage

What is the  difference between the words "unbiased" and "impartial" in terms of formality, usage, meaning?

Comment: There isn't a dime's worth of difference between them.

Comment: They are indeed very close synonyms. If there is a difference, the first is a negation of a personal inclination or habit of thought, while the second is a negation of allegiance to any one party to a dispute. As to formality, both are quite at home in the most formal of registers; in the most informal, both might seem a little pretentious, something like "fair" or "fair-minded" being preferable to either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comparing the definitions:

> *[unbiased](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unbiased)*
>
> adjective
>
> Showing no prejudice for or against something; impartial:
>   *his assessment of the benefits and drawbacks was unbiased*
>
> [impartial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impartial)
>
> adjective
>
> Treating all rivals or disputants equally:
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

Favoring one party in a dispute over another party in a dispute, is a **specific expression** of *bias*. Like *partial* is more specific than *biased*, *impartial* is more specific than *unbiased*. A person could be *impartial* and still harbor other *[cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases)* that influences their judgment:

> ***Cognitive biases*** are tendencies to think in certain ways that can lead
>   to systematic deviations from a standard of rationality or good
>   judgment

As an example:

Judge Jerry suffers from an [*extrinsic incentive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrinsic_incentives_bias) bias. When he sits on the bench to judge between litigants, he can be *impartial*, because his *bias* expresses equally for and against each party in the dispute. But his perception of motives will still be skewed by his bias in a way that influences his judgments. People who share his *cognitive bias* would rarely question his judgements, but those who don't share his *cognitive bias* will be inclined to challenge his judgements, even though they are delivered *impartially*.

Comment: There is also the fact that while being _biased_ is generally connected with prejudice (i.e., preconceived notions, often based on nothing factual) and is almost exclusively negative, being _partial_ can be quite neutral and is more closely connected to educated judgment based on empirical knowledge. So being _unbiased_ is more likely to mean being free of prejudgmental partiality than _impartial_. At least in my head.

Comment: Precisely, @JanusBahsJacquet!

Comment: Everyone has biases, if only that I prefer vanilla to chocolate ice cream, but healthy people can acknowledge their biases and accommodate the biases of others so that they can be impartial in their judgments.