# Objective or Impartial or Unbiassed information?

Tags: word-choice

I've already read this post: [Unbiased vs Impartial difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257350/unbiased-vs-impartial-difference) , but what I wanted to know is which one to use when refering to information without bias or prejudice. Objective information, impartial information or unbiased information ? or is the same?

To put you in context, I'm talking about giving drug information without prejuidce. I'm working on a harm reduction project for a local NGO in which we are planning to go to raves and electronic music parties to give information about psychoactive susbtances.

Thanks

Comment: could you expand on the example? Giving drug information to whom, for what purpose?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question.

Comment: And when you refer to "drug information", are you referring to legal medicines, or to potentially illegal drugs?

Comment: Illegal drugs, information about MDMA, LSD, marijuana, cocaine, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial in the Oxford on-line dictionary is defined as:

> Favouring one side in a dispute above the other; biased

One definition of bias is:

> A systematic distortion of a statistical result due to a factor not allowed for in its derivation.

This is the definition most relevant to information. If you say you are giving impartial information the you are presenting information which is fair to both sides of the argument, not exaggerating the risks, and not understating them either.

However, even if the information is impartial, it could still be biased in a statistical sense. For example, if evidence shows that 25% of people who take drug X experience problem Y, this information may be unintentionally biased because we don't know for sure how many people actually  take X, and some people who get problem Y may not be counted because they don't tell anyone, or because thy get problem Z which is worse and so are not recorded. An investigation will attempt to take such factors into account, but there could still be some bias one way or the other.

So if you say "impartial" you are stating that you are not deliberately playing anything up or down. If you say "unbiased" in the sense of scientific data then you are claiming something more about the method in which the data was obtained.

In this case "impartial" seems better than "unbiased" if you intend to say that you are not allowing personal feelings or the objectives of the project to affect the information you give. You may believe that simply giving the facts is all you need to do, giving people the chance to make up their own minds. If you want to emphasise that it is not your intention to distort the picture in order to achieve you goal of harm reduction, then impartial is a good word, and will make it clear to the NGO etc, how you are approaching the issue, with facts not propaganda. They then cannot complain that your material is not persuasive  enough.

Either way "objective" also sounds good.

Comment: thanks! very clear, I also think impartial is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to your project as "a harm reduction project". That clearly implies that you consider the drugs to be "harmful".

In that case, I don't think that you can reasonably state that your information is either "impartial" or "unbiased" - see the post on [Unbiased vs Impartial difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257350/unbiased-vs-impartial-difference) which you linked to.

I also question whether you can literally refer to it as "**objective**", given the following definition and synonyms:

> **objective**
>   (of a person or their judgement) not influenced by personal feelings or opinions in considering and representing facts.
>   *‘historians try to be objective and impartial’*
>   **Synonyms:** impartial, unbiased, unprejudiced, non-partisan, disinterested, non-discriminatory, neutral, uninvolved, even-handed, equitable, fair, fair-minded, just, open-minded, dispassionate, detached, impersonal, unemotional, clinical
>   *from* [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/objective)

The other term you use - "without prejudice" - may be appropriate, on the assumption that your views *are* "based on reason or actual experience":

> **prejudice**
>   Preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience.
>   *from* [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudice)

You may also consider "factual":

> **factual**
>   Concerned with what is actually the case.
>   *from* [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/factual)

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser! It's not my consideration, drug abuse, or drug use but without having some precaussions can be harmfull. Example: Take 15 MDMA pills at once is harmfull. I understand your point, but I think, after reading davidlol anwser, impartial is the best option. (sorry for my non-native english)

Comment: I wasn't disputing that the drugs can be harmful - I was merely basing my comments on the definitions of the words, and on the assumed evidence.  That is why I opted for 'factual'.

Comment: Now I don't know which one to use :/ I'll use both!

Comment: Look what I found on a site of a similar project from the US, they say: Provide honest, fact-based, unbiased information on drug effects and potential harms to empower users to make informed decisions;